# Creating nested elements in JQuery using $() constructor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I can't get JQuery's $() element constructor to work right. The following works right (using expect.js for the `expect()` calls):

```
var p = $('<div id="1"><div id="2">middle div</div></div>');
expect(p.children('div')).not.to.be(undefined); //passes
expect(p.children('div').attr('id')).to.equal('2'); //passes
```

But the following doesn't work

```
var p = $('<p id="1"><div id="2">middle div</div></p>');
expect(p.children('div')).not.to.be(undefined); //passes
expect(p.children('div').attr('id')).to.equal('2'); //fails
```

Any tips on how to get this to work right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTML markup is wrong. You cannot put a block-level element like `<div>` into a `<p>` element. That's why the HTML is actually (I think this depends on the browser) most likely parsed as:

```
<p id="1"></p><div id="2">middle div</div>
```

or (in chrome):

```
<p id="1"></p><div id="2">middle div</div><p></p>
```

You can verify this easily via `console.log(p);`

Comment: Fixed it right up! Thanks. Here's a quick ref for what can contain what for future reference: http://risd.generic.cx/containment.html

Answer (score 1):

The `<div>` is being ejected because it's not valid to have a `<div>` inside a `<p>`.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

```
expect($('#1').find('div').attr('id').to.equal('2');
```

Edit: Niko and The System are right.. a div cannot be in a p though.